# Excel: Concatenate cells for all rows with a common field value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I need to concatenate data from one column onto another for all rows which have matching data in an ID column.

I will then discard all but single items and the first item for multiples, so I do need to keep the data inline within a new column, rather than via a new table or sheet.

For example.

```
ID  DATA    COMBINED          

A   Apple   Apple             

B   Pear    Pear Banana       

B   Banana  Pear Banana       

C   Cherry  Cherry            

D   Apple   Apple Peach Pear  

D   Peach   Apple Peach Pear  

D   Pear    Apple Peach Pear
```

I've looked at [Concatenate (Excel) rows based on common cell, including different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413299/concatenate-excel-rows-based-on-common-cell-including-different-columns) and [Excel: Group values from rows based on common cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125972/excel-group-values-from-rows-based-on-common-cell-value) but neither solution is quite what I am looking for.

My sheet has about 90 columns so it's a bit of a beast.

Appreciate any pointers or guidance on this one.

Many thanks

Comment: [this may be of use](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values)

Comment: What have you tried?  You could use worksheet functions, but it is a trivial task using `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`) if you have Excel 2010+.

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad, that's pretty much what I have been trying. I think I have been making my life more difficult by trying to keep all the data in the same rows. I've subsequently followed the advice on your link and in my original post and have created a new table with unique data, concatenated the columns and then pulled the result back into the original table via a simple VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **POWER QUERY Approach** - available in Excel 2010 and later versions

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use Power Query on your version of Excel. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Suppose you have put the data range into a **Table**, use **From Table** function to add it to Power Query Editor and it should look like this:

[image: Step 1 From Table]

Then use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab of the editor to group the data as shown below:

[image: Step 2 Group By]

Go to the formula bar and replace the formula as following

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([DATA], " "), type text}})
```

The key is to replace the `List.Sum` function after `each` with `Text.Combine` function of **Power Query M** language.

The table will be updated as:

[image: Step 3 - Text Combine]

Then you can **Close & Load** the output of this query to a new worksheet (by default).

Here is the full code behind the scene for reference only.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"DATA", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"Sum", each Text.Combine([DATA], " "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Also a valid answer without using formulae. Thanks Terry, I wasn't aware of this approach.